# AzureMobileService RazorEngine dependency

Tags: dependencies, azure-mobile-services, razorengine

I have met issue when I tried to update RazorEngine to v3.6.4 (actually exception start to occur after v3.5 +) for my AzureMobileService project:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Method not found: 'System.String RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplate.Run(RazorEngine.Templating.ExecuteContext)'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.MissingMethodException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Content.HtmlActionResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

I need the last version for my internal purposes.

Service works correct but gui doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your code depending on RazorEngine or something else? I guess you need to recompile whatever is depending on RazorEngine... If the code depending on RazorEngine is out of your control you need to ask them to update...

Comment: @matthid yes, AzureMobileServices SDK is depending.

Comment: Then you need to update AzureMobileServices SDK to a version supporting the latest RazorEngine...

Comment: Actually there is no documentation about this (Is the last AzureMobileService SDK supports the last version of RazorEngine). So I'm not sure that updating (that actually isn't so simple to do) give any benefits.

Comment: Then you can only stay on an outdated version. 3.5 had some breaking changes and a new API (it still is 3.X because 3 stands for Razor3).